# JQuery scrollTop animate unwanted call

Tags: jquery, css

I´m developing a small webpage and I want to change the background-color of the navbar when scroled down.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').animate({'background-color' : '#999999'}, 'slow');
        //$('nav').css("background-color","#cccccc");
    }
    else {
        $('nav').animate({'background-color' : '#eeeecc'}, 'slow');
        //$('nav').css("background-color","#eeeecc");
    }
})
```

when i am scrolling to the top, the if-statement is called instantly and the else-statement after round about 10 seconds. But the else-statement should be executed instantly.

If am am using the commented lines of code instead, it workes.

Answer (score 0):

What works is using the stop function:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').animate({'background-color' : '#999999'}, 'slow'); 
    }
    else {
        $('nav').stop(true,true);
        $('nav').animate({'background-color' : '#eeeecc'}, 'slow');
    }
})
```

but I'm not sure if this is a good solution.